# Why does Spivak assert that $1\ne 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Spivak, *Calculus*, prologue, page 6 says:

> Moreover, $1\ne 0$. (The assertion may seem a strange fact to list, but
>   we have to list it, because there is no way it could possibly be
>   proved on the basis of the other properties listed - these properties
>   would all hold if there were only one number, namely, $0$).

I did not understand what would go wrong without that assertion. $a*1 = 1*a = a$ couldn't hold true if $1 = 0$.

Comment: If you assume that $1 =0$, then you see that every element is $0$ because $a\cdot 1 = a \cdot 0 = 0$. This is fairly noninteresting.

Comment: You don't get a contradiction.  But you get something utterly trivial.  $a = 1*a = 0*a = 0$.  So your field consists of only one element: $0$ with the property $0+0 =0$ and $0*0 = 0$.  That's too boring to even bother with.

Comment: @Chickenmancer: multiplication by $1$ is perfectly well defined, because the field only contains one element: $1\times 1 = 1 = 0$.

Comment: @Chickenmancer.  It's perfectly well-defined!  $0$ (and therefore $1$) don't have multiplicative inverses.  But the result is a trivial field with only one element.  And there's utterly nothing wrong with $1=2$.  *EVERYTHING* is equal to $1$ which is equal to $0$.  It's just very boring.

Comment: @fleablood: $1$ certainly does have a multiplicative inverse: $1\times 1=1$. And $0$ has a multiplicative inverse too, but this is not required by the field axioms :-)

Comment: @TonyK  good point.  I mean and should have said "don't need to have multiplicative inverses".  My point being $\frac 10$ need not be defined (although it is).  The conclusion that $1 = 2$ is not a contradiction however.

Comment: " there is no way it could possibly be proved on the basis of the other properties listed"  I think what spivak is saying is that we *know* that $1\ne 0$.  But we must state that explicitly; it can not be proven simply by the field axioms (as Spivak lists them). A field (with one element) where $1 = 0$ is consistent with the axioms as Spivak lists them.